# How to avoid being blocked by deadlocks?

Tags: postgresql

Can I write an `UPDATE` statement that will simply not bother executing if there's a deadlock?

I have a small, but frequently updated table.

This statement is run quite frequently on it....

```
UPDATE table_a SET lastChangedTime = 'blah' WHERE pk = 1234;
```

Where `pk` is the primary key.

Every now and again this statement gets blocked. That's not in itself a big deal; the issue is that each time there's a lock it seems to take a minute or two for Postgres to sort itself out, and I can lose a lot a data.

`table_a` is very volatile, and `lastChangedTime` gets altered all the time, so rather than occasionally having to wait two minutes for the `UPDATE` to get executed, I'd rather it just didn't bother. Ok, my data might not be as up-to-date as I'd like for this one record, but at least I wouldn't have locked the whole table for 2 minutes.

---

Update following comments:

the application interacts very simply with the database, it only issues simple, one line `UPDATE` and `INSERT` statements, and commits each one immediately. One of the issues causing me a lot of head scratching is how can something work a million times without problem, and then just fail on another record that appears to be identical to all the others.

---

Final suggestion/question.....
The UPDATE statement is being invoked from a C# application. If I change the 'command timeout' to a very short value - say 1 millisecond would that have the desired effect? or might it end up clogging up the database with lots of broken transactions?

Comment: A real deadlock will be killed by the database and a (detected) deadlock is always an application bug. But your description sounds as if it's a "normal" lock and your transaction  is simply waits until a different transaction releases the lock on the row. That again is caused by your application - you need to release the locks faster, maybe your application is doing other stuff before it commits.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - what's the difference between a 'real deadlock' and a 'detected deadlock'

Comment: An application can create deadlocks that involve resources that are not part of the database. Those can't be detected by the database. But a deadlock that involves only rows in the database will always be detected and one of the transactions causing the deadlock will be killed by the server. Also: a single update (as shown) will not lock the whole table. It only locks the row that is updated. I'm pretty sure there is something else going on. You could check pg_stat_activiy when it happens to see which transaction is blocking your update

Answer (score 0):

To avoid waiting for locks, first run

```
SELECT 1 FROM table_a WHERE pk = 1234 FOR UPDATE NOWAIT;
```

If there is a lock on the row, the statement will fail immediately, and you can go o working on something different.

Mind that the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` statement has to be in the same database transaction as your `UPDATE` statement.

As a general advice, you should use shorter transactions, which will reduce the length of lock waits and the risk of deadlock.